# Using a Zener to offset split rail?

Tags: voltage-regulator, zener, voltage-reference

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYkO08.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

i've searched but can't find a definite answer, is it possible to use the standard resistor divider but with a Zener in the middle to offset a Feedback voltage required for a Buck regulator IC? I'm already aware of the high current and stable LM317/337 combo for a mid rail, this uses a 2.5v Zener middle to obtain +-1.25v respectively for each regulator
After studying some active Lithium balancing topologies, i see circuits using tiny buck regulators for balancing every pair of cells, being a Shed hobbyist, i'd like to build a bigger & cheaper version... a bit of research brought me to the Mini360 which uses MP2307 and a V-ref of 0.925/1.1v to cycle the inductor.... so following the LM317/337 model, if i use a 2v0 Zener (BZX55c) between a pair of carefully matched 1% 1.2k R's, this should shift the voltage by 1v (approx) from center and the current across the resistor divider calculated for 8.4-6.0v and enough Ma for the stable(ish) 2.0v drop (1.2-2Mah for the Zener according to the datasheet).... am i understanding this correctly or am i going about it the completely wrong way?  i'd dearly love to hear your Fb on this. ;) Pun intended, thank you for enduring my first post.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. A schematic is better than words. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Dammit, i knew not using any "virtual" schematic would come back to haunt me, sorry... i'm really old-school and never got around to learning any of those programs.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor i appreciate your prompt interaction, i'll learn how to computer schematic then come back... i may be some time (just had a quick look)

Comment: It's really very easy and I've given you pretty much all the instructions you need. Hit the [edit] link and then the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Someone can tidy it up afterwards if you're struggling.

Comment: So... I learned how to schematic online, and had my first try at simulators...  The answers were there all along, i was simply looking in the wrong place.  I had other ideas relating but won't ask here, the simulator programs exceptionally helpful.  Sorry to have bothered you guys.

Comment: No problem. If you think your learnings may be helpful to someone else you can write them up as an answer and accept it (after a delay period of 8 or 24 hours, I think) to indicate that the question has been solved.